# Hook modifier falloff not working

Tags: modeling, modifiers, proportional-editing

In Blender's hook modifier, it looks like the falloff, which should behave like proportional edit in edit mode isn't working. None of the tutorials I have found online show how to make proportional edit work.

This is a vanilla blender problem. There is nothing distinct about this scene or edit mode that prevents it from working.

The steps of using the hook modifier are:
In object mode add a hook modifier to object.
Assign vertex groups you want to effect in the modifier
Create an empty and assign as the object to the hook modifier.

No change to the falloff or strength changes anything in Blender
This is version 2.91

Comment: Too little information. Please add screenshots.

Comment: or add blend file. You want help - so help us with as much detail as needed so we can help at all.

Comment: This would be the same in any blend file but I here are the steps of adding the modifier:  add the hook modifier assign it to the vertex group of points you want to select. Falloff should affect the position of surrounding vertices just like with proportional edit but it doesn't. I need clarification if this is a bug in the falloff feature or if I'm missing a step. No tutorial I've seen has used falloff successfully.

Comment: Falloff does work but it requires some unexpected setup; you need to Assign multiple verticies to the modifier in Edit mode. I can add a proper answer later but for now select the mesn, go into 'Edit' mode, select the surrounding vertices and click 'Assign' on the modifier panel. Make sure the 'Radius' is non-zero (as zero indicates 'all').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Falloff of the influence of a Hook does work but it requires some unexpected setup; you need to Assign multiple verticies to the modifier in Edit mode rather than rely on the 'Vertex Group' to indicate the affectedvertices.

Hooking to a single vert will move just that vertex. However, in Edit mode you can also 'Assign' other vertices to the modifier - it is these 'assigned' vertices that are affected by the 'Falloff' of the modifier. A Radius of zero inicates 'no falloff' (so all vertices are affected equally). Therefore, the steps you require are to select and 'assign' the surrounding vertices and then increase the Radius and Type until the required effect is achieved. This is demonstrated in the following image :

[image: animated demonstration]

Comment: If a vg is used in conjunction with above, will their weights be taken into calculation?

Comment: @batFINGER Yes - the Vertex Group setting effectively acts after the modifier and controls how much actual influence the vertices in that group are affected by the modifier. So the 'Assign' within the modifier controls what the modifier does and the Vertex Group controls how much that affects the vertices (with weighting).